# Python nested loop simplification

Tags: python, loops, range

In Python I have a series of nested `for` loops in this format:

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
      for k in range(2):
```

and so on, all with the same range. Is there an easy way to simplify this into something like:
for i, j, k in range(2)? I have been looking for a way to condense it down to one line and haven't found one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18369260/3001761

Comment: or [Avoiding nested for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11174745)

Comment: This isn't necessarily a dupe as it can be solved in different ways based on what the intention is.  If OP wants to select different 3-length combinations (with repeats) from a pool of 2 items, then they could iterate with "for i,j,k in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(2), 3)"

Comment: Aaaaand I just realized that I'm wrong and combinations_with_replacement didn't give what I expected.  itertools.product(range(2), repeat=3) would be correct.